# Unable to get the Content of the text file saved in the Database(My-Sql)

Tags: asp.net, mysql

In my MySql i am having my data field as `longblob` i would like to get the content in that file so i have written my code as follows

This is what i am doing before inserting

```
  string filePath = Server.MapPath("AchTemplates/genACH.txt");
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();

    string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(FName,FData) values (@_FName, @_FData)";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_FData", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = bytes;
    InsertUpdateData(cmd);
```

//Get Data

```
private void download(DataTable dt)
{
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["FData"];
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
    + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

But i am getting the content as system.string[] why it is happening can any one tell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `dt.Rows[0]["FData"]` is coming as a string (it is just `plain text`), use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dt.Rows[0]["FData"]);
```

If the data is not plain text and binary stored as string (and not base64 encoded), you are in **trouble** my friend.

---

### UPDATE

According to [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), it seems you should be using `LONGBLOB` and not `LONGTEXT`.

Comment: In my table my data is stored as System.Byte[] then how can i get Data

Comment: But you said you are using `longtext` so how this could be binary??

Comment: Check my edit once i am having a small doubt how can i declare a field as varbinary in mysql if i set it as varbinary and leaving the field it is skipping to varchar

Comment: If i use LongBlob and displaying i am getting the output in my txt file as System.string[] but not the actual data

Comment: @Aliostad  Can you tell why this is happening

Comment: @Dorababu I cannot debug the text! You have the code and can see why `System.string[]` is being written, perhaps it is the data that is going there in the first place? Maybe you refer to wrong field? Perhaps a bug in MySql provider (very unlikely)? I am not meant to code for you, just provide guidance and pointers for you to pick up and solve your problem yourself.

Comment: I am not asking you code what i have written is ok or i have to change anything in my code i.e i am asking

Comment: I have given you advice and you have made changes and now you are having other problems. First, this is a totally different question now (and you might as well post it since it is confusing the initial question and your code is not the same). Second, I am not sure `MySqlDbType.LongText` you have in the fisrt snippet if it is old or changed or what. I cannot debug your code but if `MySqlDbType.LongText` is still there, thats your problem.

Comment: I changed to the one as per you said but the problem remains the same

Comment: If i use as per you stated answer i am getting the following errors The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(char[])' has some invalid argumentsArgument '1': cannot convert from 'char' to 'char[]'

Comment: I said **if dt.Rows[0]["FData"] is coming as a `string`** but you have changed it so it is not string anymore, how do you expect the same code to work? That is what I mean, your question has changed so much that none of the discussions are relevant anymore.

Comment: After all necessary changes i used the one as per you said and it works thanks